# Pandas и openpyxl и Nan

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, nan

Есть два столбца в Excel. Один заполнен, в другом есть пустые ячейки. Задача: заменить пустые ячейки одного столбца, на значения соответствующих ячеек другого столбца. Данную задачу реализовала с помощью openpyxl :

```
    for i in range(2, sheet2.max_row + 1):
        if sheet2.cell(row=i, column=4).value==None:
            sheet2.cell(row=i, column=4).value=sheet2.cell(row=i, column=3).value
```

Хочу переписать скрипт с помощью pandas. У меня такое ощущение, что он не воспринимает NaN.
Например:

```
    in: data1['4'].unique()
    out: [nan '1']
```

Хочу заменить nan, ничего не происходит. Пробовала разные варианты.
Например:

```
    column_4=list(data1.iloc[:,4])
    column_3=list(data1.iloc[:,3])
    column_4=[[x for x in column_3] if x == None else x for x in column_4]
```

column_4-остается без изменений.
Даже если заменить на другое значение:

```
    column_4=["A" if x == None else x for x in column_4]
```

Если меняю условие:

```
    column_4=["A" if x != None else x for x in column_4]
```

Тоже он мне везде А печатает.
Есть вариант реализовать просто со столбцами, без списков?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего пустые ячейки в Excel будут прочитаны как `NaN` ("Not a Number") в Pandas. И т.к. `None` != `NaN` ваш код не будет работать:

```
In [38]: np.nan == None
Out[38]: False
```

Попробуйте воспользоваться [pd.Series.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
In [42]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3], "b":[10, np.nan, np.nan]})

In [43]: df
Out[43]:
   a     b
0  1  10.0
1  2   NaN
2  3   NaN

In [44]: df["b"] = df["b"].fillna(df["a"])

In [45]: df
Out[45]:
   a     b
0  1  10.0
1  2   2.0
2  3   3.0
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь